# How to convert hexadecimal to decimal on DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2, hex

I have a field in a db2 database which is on hexadecimal format i.e 0x0a
which is number 10 in decimal format. The hex field's datatype is `char(1) for bit data`.

```
hex(myfield) gives me the hexadecimal 0A
```

How can i convert 0x0a to 10 in a query on db2?

I have tried: `cast(hex(myfield),integer)`
and `int(hex(myfield))`
with no luck.

Is it possible?

Comment: What happens with just a bare select of the field? What about casting directly to int?

Comment: bare select gives 0x0a while hex() gives 0A.  Casting directly gives null.

Comment: in fact the initial datatype is char(1) for bit data. if i cast it as you said it gives tha same value as bare select which is 0x0a

Comment: `CHAR(1) FOR BIT DATA` in a DB2 DB are usually used for flag fields that would normally just contain '1' or '0', which would be x'F1' or x'F0' (assuming EBCIDC).  What are you using it for that it contains x'0A'?  What are you doing with the retrieved value?  Assuming you are pulling it back into some HLL, you may be bettered served converting it there.

Comment: Try simply `ASCII(myfield)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such single function built into DB2 that would perform that conversion, but there is a [blog post showing how to define such a function](https://web.archive.org/web/20200101052310/https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/bit_arithmetic19?lang=en). The following function is taken from that article:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION HEX2INT(str VARCHAR(8))
RETURNS INTEGER
SPECIFIC HEX2INT
DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION CONTAINS SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
  DECLARE res INTEGER  DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE pos INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE nibble CHAR(1);
  WHILE pos <= LENGTH(str) DO
    SET nibble = SUBSTR(str, pos, 1);
    SET res = BITOR(CASE WHEN BITAND(res, 134217728) != 0
                         THEN BITOR(16 * BITANDNOT(res, 134217728),
                                    -2147483648)
                         ELSE 16 * res END,
                    CASE nibble
                         WHEN '0' THEN 0
                         WHEN '1' THEN 1
                         WHEN '2' THEN 2
                         WHEN '3' THEN 3
                         WHEN '4' THEN 4
                         WHEN '5' THEN 5
                         WHEN '6' THEN 6
                         WHEN '7' THEN 7
                         WHEN '8' THEN 8
                         WHEN '9' THEN 9
                         WHEN 'A' THEN 10
                         WHEN 'a' THEN 10
                         WHEN 'B' THEN 11
                         WHEN 'b' THEN 11
                         WHEN 'C' THEN 12
                         WHEN 'c' THEN 12
                         WHEN 'D' THEN 13
                         WHEN 'd' THEN 13
                         WHEN 'E' THEN 14
                         WHEN 'e' THEN 14
                         WHEN 'F' THEN 15
                         WHEN 'f' THEN 15
                         ELSE RAISE_ERROR('78000', 'Not a hex string') 
                         END),
        pos = pos + 1;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN res;
END
@
--#SET TERMINATOR ;
```

There are more functions for various conversion operations described.

Comment: I find it unbelievable that there is no way in DB2 to simply access the numeric value of such a field directly.  Any idea why?

Comment: different market - hex is less used in financial, banking, retail

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you could simplify the following

```
WITH fred (x) AS (VALUES 'f1'), 

     nurk (a) as (SELECT UPPER(substr(x,1)) from fred 
                  union all 
                  select UPPER(substr(a,2)) from nurk 
                   where substr(a,1,1) <> ' '), 

     bare (b, c) as (select substr(a,1,1), (length(a) - 1) 
                  from nurk), 

     trap (d) as ((SELECT (ASCII(B) - ASCII('7')) * 
                   power(16,c) 
                   FROM BARE 
                   WHERE (B BETWEEN 'A' AND 'F') 
                   and 
                   c <> -1) 
                   union 
                  (SELECT (ASCII(B) - ASCII('0')) * 
                   power(16,c) 
                   FROM BARE 
                   WHERE (B not BETWEEN 'A' AND 'F') 
                   and 
                   c <> -1)) 
select sum(d) from trap
```

ran as

db2 -f "filename of above"

gave result of

241

try testing with values other than f1

John Hennesy

Answer (score 0):

In Standard SQL (I hope so):

```
with inp (val) as                                                
(values ('FF'), ('AB'), ('ABCDEF')),                             
     calc(val, urval, res, f) as                                 
(select case when length(val) > 1                                
                  then substr(val, 1, length(val)-1)             
             else '' end, val,                                   
        locate(right(val, 1),'0123456789ABCDEF')-1, 16           
 from   inp                                                      
 union  all                                                      
 select case when length(val) > 1                                
                  then substr(val, 1, length(val)-1)             
             else '' end, urval,                                 
        res + ((locate(right(val, 1),'0123456789ABCDEF')-1) * f),
        f * 16                                                   
 from   calc                                                     
 where  length(val) > 0)                                         
select  urval, res 
from    calc                                     
where   val = ''
```

==>

URVAL             RES
FF                255
AB                171
ABCDEF     11.259.375

Comment: Not standard. ISO/ANSI SQL has no substr or locate.

Answer (score 0):

```
convert( datatype, column_Name)
```

Ex:  `convert(decimal(18,2), column_Name)`
--here column_Name has Hexadecimal value

Answer (score -4):

The syntax is as follows

```
select CONVERT(int, 0xFFFFFF)
```

Check the documentation below should you need more details on converting to and from specific datatypes

**Data types**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187594(v=sql.105).aspx

**Converting data types**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: This is a great answer for SQL Server, but the question was about DB2.